# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput output file does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to implement custom video recording and image capture in my app. I've setup the AVCaptureSession and all the necessary inputs/outputs to capture audio, video, and still images. However, the output file does not exist after I finish recording a video. Since there is no file at the output url, I cannot save the video to the users Photo Library.

Why is the output file not being created? Is there a setting I'm missing on `self.videoOutput` (`AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`)?

`startRecording` implementation:

```
func startRecording() throws {
    if !self.recording {
        let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
        let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)

        self.videoOutput.startRecording(to: url, recordingDelegate: self)
    }
}
```

`AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` implementation.

```
extension MainViewController: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didStartRecordingTo fileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection]) {
    self.recording = true
    //FileManager.default.fileExists(fileURL.absoluteString) == false
}

func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    self.recording = false
    //FileManager.default.fileExists(outputFileURL.absoluteString) == false

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputFileURL)
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputFileURL)
            } catch _ as NSError {
                //error
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ends up there were two issues:

First - I was checking to see if the file existed using the wrong code. The correct way to check if the file existed is this:

```
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputFileURL.path)
```

Second - The Photos framework didn't except a UUID as a valid file name. Once I added a ".mov" extension to the file name, the framework was able to save the video to the Photos app. Working code below:

```
let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString + ".mov")
```

Comment: I'm facing same error. Actually where should we create the url and where should we remove it.